# How to list files in a Google Storage bucket with fog-google

Tags: fog, fog-google

Using [fog-google](https://github.com/fog/fog-google) and [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/), how does one list files in a bucket with a given prefix?

This hangs:

```
require 'fog/google'
storage = Fog::Storage.new(:provider => 'Google', :google_project => project, :google_json_key_string => json_data)
storage.directories.get(bucket_name, prefix: prefix).files
```

A similar task on S3 using [fog-aws](https://github.com/fog/fog-aws) works fine:

```
require 'fog/aws'
storage = Fog::Storage.new(provider: 'AWS', aws_access_key_id: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key: aws_secret_access_key)
storage.directories.get(bucket_name, prefix: prefix).files.each do |f|
  puts f.key
end
```

In both code snippets above, assume that relevant variables are set correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Following Google instruction here :

[https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/using-cloud-storage][1]

```
FogStorage = Fog::Storage.new(provider: "Google",  
   google_storage_access_key_id:     config["access_key_id"],  
   google_storage_secret_access_key: config["secret_access_key"] )

StorageBucket = FogStorage.directories.new key: config["bucket"]
puts StorageBucket.files.inspect
```

I think your trouble is in FogStorage.directories.new

Comment: With the google_json_key_string, the google_storage_access_key_id can not be used.